# Error in `[.data.frame`(e.wide, first.var:last.var) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, igraph

Would you please tell me what exactly the error I get when running the following program means?

Can somebody help with this error related to .data.frame ?

```
Xegonetlist6 = read.egonet.one.file(egos=Xegonet.data5,
             netsize=Xegonet.data5$listed.degree, egoID = "id"
            ,attr.start.col=20,attr.end.col=29,
            dy.max.alteri=10, dy.first.var=30, ego.vars = c(1:17), var.wise = T)
```

> Sorting data by egoID. Transforming alteri data to long format.
> Deleting NA rows in long alteri data. Splitting long alteri data into
> list entries for each network: $alteri.list Combining trimmed
> alteri.list to data.frame: $alteri.df Transforming wide dyad data to
> edgelist: $edges Error in `[.data.frame`(e.wide, first.var:last.var) :
> undefined columns selected  @Ari B. Friedman

Comment: Hi, please try making a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help answer your question.

Comment: @grapestory thanks for you help. I am tring to convert my data to egor objects.(egoid=id, A-G), Alter A1sx-A5F), alter-alter tie (e12-e45). Sample data: id.  A B C D E F G actual.degree listed.degree A1sx A2sx A3sx A4sx A5sx A1F A2F A3F A4F A5F e12 e13 e14 e15 e23 e24 e25 e34 e35 e45
1 1 32 1 17 0.5 1 1 1 1 3 3 5 5 5 5 5 6 5 1 1 1 1 1 11 10 10 10 11 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
2 0 29 1 15 0 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 1 2 5 5 10 5 1 1 1 1 1 10 12 11 12 11 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
3 1 49 1 19 0.5 1 1 1 1 5 5 5 1 4 5 5 3 3 1 1 1 0 0 11 11 11 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. When @grapestory asked for reprex, your comment doesn't work. The reprex could be copied and used by someone attempting to answer your question, whereas your comment is not helpful. You could also try using `dput(data)` to make your question reproducible. Instead of adding it in a comment, click on edit on the bottom left of your question. [You can read more about reproducible questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).